# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: javascript

I have a currently fairly dysfunctional Javascript program that's been causing me problems. However, it throws one error that I just don't understand:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'sub.from.length')
```

What I'm trying to do, as you can probably guess, is check the `length` of a certain "`from`" array in the `sub` dict. Here's the [source code for the entire function](http://pastebin.com/RVDkJe3d), and here's the code of the loop that I think is causing the error:

```
console.log(afcHelper_ffuSubmissions.length); // just for debugging, returns the correct number
for (var i = 0; i < afcHelper_ffuSubmissions.length; i++) { // this whole section works fine
    var sub = afcHelper_ffuSubmissions[i];
    //console.log("THIS IS BROKEN DOWN BY LINK",afcHelper_Submissions[i]);
    if (pagetext.indexOf(afcHelper_ffuSections[sub.section]) == -1) {
        // Someone has modified the section in the mean time. Skip.
        document.getElementById('afcHelper_status').innerHTML += '<li>Skipping ' + sub.title + ': Cannot find section. Perhaps it was modified in the mean time?</li>';
        continue;
    }
    var text = afcHelper_ffuSections[sub.section];
    var startindex = pagetext.indexOf(afcHelper_ffuSections[sub.section]);
    var endindex = startindex + text.length;

    console.log(sub); 
    if (typeof(sub.from) != 'undefined' && sub.from.length > 0) { // ** problem spot?? this is the code i recently added.
        for (var i = 0; i < sub.from.length; i++) {
            mainid = sub.from[i]['id'];
            var sub = afcHelper_Submissions[mainid]; // and then it goes on from here...
```

Any ideas would be great. Frankly, I just can't see why I'm getting a `TypeError` about something that I've already explicitly checked the type of (`typeof(sub.from)`)...

Comment: Use a Javascript debugger like Firebug or the built-in debugger of Chrome. You can put a breakpoint there and investigate your variables.

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Comment: Maybe sub.from is null: `typeof(null) != "undefined";//=true`

Comment: What is console output of `console.log(sub)` and `console.log(sub.from)`?

Comment: @HMR, my Firefox gives me `TypeError: variable is null` then.

Comment: @BartFriederichs  I know, that's why I say maybe. I can't reproduce this in any browser so maybe the OP didn't copy and paste the error but re typed what they think they read (without wearing their glasses)

Comment: @HMR Haha, nice try. :p I copy/pasted the error msg straight from Safari's debugger, and here's the output from the console.logging http://pastebin.com/t08SYGKz

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure how you could just check if something isn't undefined and at the same time get an error that it is undefined. What browser are you using?

You could check in the following way (extra = and making length a truthy evaluation)

```
if (typeof sub !== 'undefined' && sub.from && sub.from.length) {
```

**[update]**

I see that you reset sub and thereby reset sub.from but fail to re check if sub.from exist:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sub.from.length; i++) {//<== assuming sub.from.exist
            mainid = sub.from[i]['id'];
            var sub = afcHelper_Submissions[mainid]; // <== re setting sub
```

My guess is that the error is not on the if statement but on the `for(i...` statement. In Firebug you can break automatically on an error and I guess it'll break on that line (not on the if statement).

Comment: I'm using Safari on Mac OS 10.8; tried it with your code and got the same error, http://i.imgur.com/XZEnl2V.png -- will try in another browser and report back with its error message, if that helps...

Comment: @user1483482 I wonder what the data is. It's strange something not be undefined and be undefined at the same time.

Comment: Google Chrome says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` :/

Comment: Well, sub.from is just an Array.

Comment: @user1483482 What is the output of `console.log(typeof(sub.from));`?

Comment: The utterly informative "object"...huh, yet the debugger says "Array[1]" next to it... it's prototype is Array. But typeof says object.

Comment: @user1483482 Updated my answer and in the future if you want to log something that actually helps you can use Firefox with firebug or Chrome.

Comment: Also, very Bad Practice to touch the array you are iterating over.

Answer (score -3):

try out this if you want to assign value to object and it is showing this error in angular..

crate object in construtor

`this.modelObj = new Model();` //<----------   after declaring object above