# JS error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dataText[i].length')"

Tags: javascript

Although this piece of code work as intended i.e. prints the text, there is a console error on line 32 that reads: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dataText[i].length')"

Any ideas why?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event){
  // array with texts to type in typewriter
  var dataText = [ "Hi", "it's Acephala", "Shipping is free for you today",];

  // type one text in the typwriter
  // keeps calling itself until the text is finished
  function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
    // chekc if text isn't finished yet
    if (i < (text.length)) {
      // add next character to h1
     document.querySelector("h1animation").innerHTML = text.substring(0, i+1) +'<spananimation aria-hidden="true"></spananimation>';

      // wait for a while and call this function again for next character || BK: Speed of text writing
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback)
      }, 100);
    }
    // text finished, call callback if there is a callback function
    else if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') {
      // call callback after timeout
      setTimeout(fnCallback, 700);
    }
  }
  // start a typewriter animation for a text in the dataText array
   function StartTextAnimation(i) {
     if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined'){
        setTimeout(function() {
          StartTextAnimation(0);
        }, 20000);
     }
     // check if dataText[i] exists
    if (i < dataText[i].length) {
      // text exists! start typewriter animation
     typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function(){
       // after callback (and whole text has been animated), start next text
       StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
     });
    }
  }
  // start the text animation
  StartTextAnimation(0);
});
```

Comment: Please don't game the system by tweaking titles to avoid duplicate titles.  This question IS a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716070/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716070/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object)

Answer (score 2):

Your code does:

```
if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined'){
  ...
}
if (i < dataText[i].length) {
  ...
}
```

That means `i < dataText[i].length` is evaluated even if `dataText[i]` is `undefined`. Either add a `return` statement at the end of the first `if` block or use `else if (i < dataText[i].length) {`

---

Besides that I believe the check should actually be `i < dataText.length`. It doesn't seem reasonable to compare the length of `dataText[i]` to `i`.

If you do that change instead then the change mentioned first is not necessary.

However, in that case I'd rather but the checks inside the callback, which means that `StartTextAnimation` always receives a valid index:

```
function StartTextAnimation(i) {
  typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function(){
    // after callback (and whole text has been animated), start next text
    if (i === dataText.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        StartTextAnimation(0);
      }, 20000);
    } else {
      StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Since this is an obvious duplicate, and the problem has been asked and answered many times, it would be extra good if you threw in _troubleshooting techniques_ to add something new to the conversation.  For example: errors almost _always_ indicate what the line number is of the offending code, then how to inspect the values, etc.